# Any plans to use Firefox sync in Thunderbird?

Tags: firefox, synchronization, thunderbird

I was wondering if there are any plans to use Mozilla Firefox sync in Mozilla Thunderbird?

It would be nice if I can sync my mail profile as easy as date in Firefox.

Comment: I think you should rather ask this on a Thunderbird mailing list.

Comment: I want this, too, but this is the wrong place to ask.  Try here: https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/firefox_sync_contacts_in_thunderbird